# Oracle sql merge to insert and delete but not update

Tags: sql, oracle, merge, insert, sql-delete

Is there a way to use oracle merge to insert and delete but not update?

I have a table representing a set of values related to a single row in another table.  I could change the set of values by deleting them all and adding back the new set, or by selectively deleting some and adding others, but I am interested in making it a single statement if possible.

Here is a working example with update.  In order to make this work, I had to add `dummy` so that a column was available to update that was not in the `on` condition.  Is there some way to only delete and insert without a dummy column to update?

No column from the `on` condition may be in the `update set` list even if it is not actually updated.

```
create table every_value ( the_value varchar2(32) );
create table paired_value ( the_id number, a_value varchar2(32) , dummy number default 0 );
-- the_id is a foreign_key to a row in another table

insert into every_value ( the_value ) values ( 'aaa' );
insert into every_value ( the_value ) values ( 'abc' );
insert into every_value ( the_value ) values ( 'ace' );
insert into every_value ( the_value ) values ( 'adg' );
insert into every_value ( the_value ) values ( 'aei' );
insert into every_value ( the_value ) values ( 'afk' );

-- pair ace and afk with id 3
merge into paired_value p using every_value e
on ( p.the_id = 3 and p.a_value = e.the_value )
when matched then update set dummy=dummy+1
delete where a_value not in ('ace','afk')
when not matched then insert (the_id,a_value)
values (3,e.the_value)
where e.the_value in ('ace','afk');

-- pair ace and aei with id 3
-- should remove afk, add aei, do nothing with ace
merge into paired_value p using every_value e
on ( p.the_id = 3 and p.a_value = e.the_value )
when matched then update set dummy = dummy+1
delete where a_value not in ('ace','aei')
when not matched then insert (the_id,a_value)
values (3,e.the_value)
where e.the_value in ('ace','aei');

-- pair aaa and adg with id 4
merge into paired_value p using every_value e
on ( p.the_id = 4 and p.a_value = e.the_value )
when matched then update set dummy = dummy+1
delete where a_value not in ('aaa','adg')
when not matched then insert (the_id,a_value)
values (4,e.the_value)
where e.the_value in ('aaa','adg');

select * from paired_value;
```

I have tried this in oracle 10g and, with this [sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/a25ac/1), oracle 11g.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

No, you cannot delete rows that have not been updated by the merge command.
Here is documentation: http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28286/statements_9016.htm

> Specify the DELETE where_clause to clean up data in a table while
>   populating or updating it. **The only rows affected by this clause are
>   those rows in the destination table that are updated by the merge
>   operation**. The DELETE WHERE condition evaluates the updated value, not
>   the original value that was evaluated by the UPDATE SET ... WHERE
>   condition. If a row of the destination table meets the DELETE
>   condition but is not included in the join defined by the ON clause,
>   then it is not deleted. Any delete triggers defined on the target
>   table will be activated for each row deletion.

That means, that rows **must** be updated. Hovewer, you don't need to update all rows, after UPDATE use the same WHERE clause as you are using after DELETE

```
when matched then update set dummy=dummy
    where a_value not in ('ace','afk')
delete 
    where a_value not in ('ace','afk')
```

Comment: I was fairly sure there was no better way than having a dummy column, but I am not going to add a dummy column just for this.  Oh well.

Answer (score 1):

I have found you can set the column to itself:

```
MERGE ...
WHEN MATCHED THEN 
   UPDATE SET a_value = a_value WHERE a_value not in ('ace','afk')
   DELETE WHERE a_value not in ('ace','afk')
```

This negates the need for the dummy column.

Comment: Is as_value in your ON condition? This did not work for me in 11g if the column is in the ON condition I get a "Columns referenced in the ON Clause cannot be updated" error even if the update is setting the value to itself.

Comment: That is correct. Per oracle documentation you cannot update a column that is part of the ON clause. If you think about it, it makes sense. 
But you could use a different Non-dummy column in the update; without having tried it I don't know if the delete clause would still trigger the same error though? E.g. SET b_value = b_value where a_value not in ('ace','afk') DELETE where a_value not in ('ace','afk').