# when i run the procedure i get this error [Err] ORA-24344: success with compilation error missing keyword

Tags: oracle

```
CREATE OR REPLACE 
PROCEDURE "UNASSIGN_CUSTOMER_FEATURES" 
(CustomerID_Param IN NUMBER, FeatureID_Param IN NUMBER, WalletID_Param IN NUMBER)
AS
BEGIN

DELETE FROM CUSTOMER_EXTRA_FEATURES WHERE FEATURES_ID = FeatureID_Param 
AND CUSTOMER_ID = CustomerID_Param;

MERGE INTO CUSTOMER_SERVICE_CONFIG c
USING 
            (SELECT BUSINESS_SERVICE_CONFIG.ID from BUSINESS_SERVICE_CONFIG join SERVICE_CONFIG_MAP 
                    ON BUSINESS_SERVICE_CONFIG.Business_SERVICE_TYPE = SERVICE_CONFIG_MAP.Service_type_ID
                    and BUSINESS_SERVICE_CONFIG.ORGANIZATION_ID = WalletID_Param
                    and BUSINESS_SERVICE_CONFIG.BUSINESSSERVICECATEGORY = 0 
                    and SERVICE_CONFIG_MAP.FEATURES_ID = FeatureID_Param ) ids

ON (c.SERVICE_CONFIG_ID = ids.ID and c.CUSTOMER_ID = CustomerID_Param )
WHEN MATCHED THEN 
DELETE WHERE CUSTOMER_ID = CustomerID_Param AND SERVICE_CONFIG_ID = ids.ID;

END;
```

Answer (score 0):

You are missing an UPDATE statement prior to doing a DELETE

something like

```
WHEN MATCHED THEN 
  UPDATE SET <some field> with <some value>
  DELETE WHERE CUSTOMER_ID = CustomerID_Param AND SERVICE_CONFIG_ID =ids.ID;
END;
```

Refer the following url:
[Oracle sql merge to insert and delete but not update](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17709602/oracle-sql-merge-to-insert-and-delete-but-not-update)

Hope that helps!

Answer (score 0):

[The syntax diagram for the merge statement](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SQLRF/statements_9016.htm#BGBBBIDF) shows that you the `delete` clause is an optional part of the `update`, not standalone:

[image]

You're getting the "ORA-00905: missing keyword" error because you don't have an `update`. You could put in a dummy update, but it looks like you really want to delete all rows that match, with no updates to other rows or inserts of new rows; which would be simpler as a plain `delete`, something like:

```
DELETE FROM CUSTOMER_SERVICE_CONFIG c
WHERE CUSTOMER_ID = CustomerID_Param
AND SERVICE_CONFIG_ID IN (
  SELECT BUSINESS_SERVICE_CONFIG.ID from BUSINESS_SERVICE_CONFIG join SERVICE_CONFIG_MAP 
  ON BUSINESS_SERVICE_CONFIG.Business_SERVICE_TYPE = SERVICE_CONFIG_MAP.Service_type_ID
  and BUSINESS_SERVICE_CONFIG.ORGANIZATION_ID = WalletID_Param
  and BUSINESS_SERVICE_CONFIG.BUSINESSSERVICECATEGORY = 0 
  and SERVICE_CONFIG_MAP.FEATURES_ID = FeatureID_Param );
```

or

```
DELETE FROM CUSTOMER_SERVICE_CONFIG c
WHERE CUSTOMER_ID = CustomerID_Param
AND EXISTS (
  SELECT null from BUSINESS_SERVICE_CONFIG join SERVICE_CONFIG_MAP 
  ON BUSINESS_SERVICE_CONFIG.Business_SERVICE_TYPE = SERVICE_CONFIG_MAP.Service_type_ID
  and BUSINESS_SERVICE_CONFIG.ORGANIZATION_ID = WalletID_Param
  and BUSINESS_SERVICE_CONFIG.BUSINESSSERVICECATEGORY = 0 
  and SERVICE_CONFIG_MAP.FEATURES_ID = FeatureID_Param
  WHERE BUSINESS_SERVICE_CONFIG.ID = c.SERVICE_CONFIG_ID );
```